# SilverLight WCF data service one query after another

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I have a foreach loop which sends WCF request as below:

```
foreach (var rec in LstPRSCRPTActivated)
{                                   
    var OrderItemQueryActivated = GV.dbContext.Load(GV.dbContext.GetOrdritemsQuery((int)rec.PresNo));                     
    OrderItemQueryActivated.Completed += new EventHandler(OrderItemQueryActivated_Completed);
}
```

In the WCF data services, I have the following code:

```
public IQueryable<OrderItem> GetOrdritems(int PresNo)
{
    return this.ObjectContext.OrderItems.Where(o => o.ScriptNo == PresNo);           
}
```

If the second query takes less time than the first, in the call back event `OrderItemQueryActivated_Completed`, I get the results from the second query and then gets the results from the first query. But I dont want to happen this way. I want to get the results of first query first followed by the second. Is there a way to do this using some kind of a wait in the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to create a composite service call that does all of the operations in a single call?  If not, you can parallel invoke all of the operations and wait until they're done to get the result.

Comment: Is it like sending a list of values(PresNo) and get the results in the a single callback?

Comment: Yup - that's it.  That way you don't get all the overhead of waiting for that many calls to complete.  Of course, you can only do this if you own the service tier (or create an additional facade layer of services).